# When I use carpet driver instead of pugh these errors generated

Tags: cygwin, cactus

I am using EINSTEIN-TOOLKIT on windows via CYGWIN.
When i run any module with CARPET driver instead of PUGH. I found these type of errors.

```
ln -s "../../opal/asm/generated/atomic-local.s" atomic-asm.S
  CPPAS    atomic-asm.lo
  CCLD     libasm.la
../../libtool: line 1744: lib: command not found
make[6]: *** [Makefile:1659: libasm.la] Error 127
make[5]: *** [Makefile:2234: all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1777: all-recursive] Error 1
Died at /home/hp/cactus/arrangements/ExternalLibraries/MPI/src/build.pl line 90.
make[3]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/arrangements/ExternalLibraries/MPI/src/make.code.deps:9: /home/hp/cactus/configs/multipole/scratch/done/MPI] Error 17
make[2]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/lib/make/make.thornlib:113: make.checked] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/lib/make/make.configuration:181: /home/hp/cactus/configs/multipole/lib/libthorn_MPI.a] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:260: multipole] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like some build-time dependencies are missing. I would not assume that the code can be straightforwardly compiled on Windows out of the box.

Comment: Sir, Today i installed Ubuntu now it's first time i am using Linux environment. I am unable to install Einstein toolkit. Please help me how i can do this. i installed in windows by Cygwin. which software i will use in Ubuntu for einstein toolkit.

Comment: Do you think I would not post an answer if I knew? If you updated your latest question to indicate *precisely* what you tried and *precisely* how it failed (or perhaps better delete that question and post a new one; but understand that *repeatedly* doing this is problematic behavior, too) someone who is familiar with this software could probably tell you how to solve your problem.